# Get same data from another field in html form

Tags: php, javascript

I'm new in Php/Mysql/Javascript. I'm learning it.

In my Html form there are 5 fields:

1. Status
2. Email Address
3. Username
4. Password
5. Agree button.

My question is "How do I get same email address to the username field ?"

Ex: **Status** = Mr, **Email Address** = emailaddress@yahoo.com, and It's should automatically fill the **username** field with this **Email address**. I believe it's can be done with Javascript. Because of javascript is a client side script.

Comment: Clarify what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell using jQuery :-

```
<script>

    $('#email_field_id').change(function(){

        $('#username_field_id').val($('#email_field_id').val())

    })
</script>
```

Or if you strictly want to use Javascript, use getElementById method,

You can add jquery plug-in into your script. Download it from here http://jquery.com/

After downloading, give path of jquery.js file above your code in  as shown below :

```
<script language="javascript" src="/* give here path of jquery.js */"></script>
```

Comment: how do i use this jQuery ?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/ http://jqfundamentals.com/

Answer (score 0):

First give id to all fields and assume you have give id as username and email_id for username and email id field then use below code

```
$('#email_id').blur(function(){
    $('#username').val($('#email_id').val());
});
```

Ensure you have included jquery in your html file...